# TSQL replace my Stored procedure string parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

My question: once I receive the parameter value, I want to modify the contents.

E.g. a string parameter value is: `FullName,Address,Category`

I want to change `FullName` to `l.FullName` and `Category` to `c.Category` and keep the rest same.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TableA] @ColNames VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    //I want to modify the contents of @ColNames here
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the before and the desired result.  Also include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
select @ColNames = replace(@ColNames, 'FullName', 'l.FullName');
select @ColNames = replace(@ColNames, 'Category', 'c.Category');
```

Comment: This is exactly what he has asked for but I bet what he is really asking for is a SP that dynamically returns certain columns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that - @ColNames is a variable - you can manipulate the contents of it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TableA] @ColNames VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    -- I want to modify the contents of @ColNames here
SET @ColNames = REPLACE(@ColNames, "FullName", "l.FullName")
SET @ColNames = REPLACE(@ColNames, "Category", "c.Category")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TableA] @ColNames VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET
        @ColNames = REPLACE(@ColNames, 'FullName', 'l.FullName')
        ;
    SET
        @ColNames = REPLACE(@ColNames, 'Category', 'c.Category')
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare 
@ColNames varchar(50)


select @ColNames = replace(@ColNames, 'FullName', 'l.FullName');
select @ColNames = replace(@ColNames, 'Category', 'c.Category');
```